# Truncating a string

Tags: c, linux, string

I have

```
char *path;
```

and I store the string "/home/juggler/file1.txt" in path. How do I truncate path so that I just have the parent of the last file/directory? In the example I would like to truncate path to "/home/juggler"

I was thinking of counting the number of characters(count) from the end to the last "/" and the copy the (length of path)-(count) to another string.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try [`dirname(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/basename.3.html) since you are on Linux. Being specified by [SUSv3](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dirname.html), it's quite portable.

> ```
> char *dirname(char *path);
> ```
>
> In the usual case, dirname() returns the string up to, but not
>   including, the final '/'.

Comment: Keep in mind that dirname alters the string, so you can't pass it string literal, (i.e. the string char *f = "/home/foo/bar" will not work, but char f[] = "/home/foo/bar"; will)

Comment: @nos...Thanks, I was passing string literal to dirname and was getting segmentation fault. when i used an array of char..it worked

Answer (score 1):

You should really use `dirname()` in `libgen.h`

```
#include <libgen.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%s\n", dirname("/home/juggler/file1.txt"));
    return 0;
}
```

Read the manpage for `dirname` for further info.